# Como combinar gráfico multi barras com gráfico scatter no HighCharts JS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Olá, estou tentando fazer um gráfico multi barras combinado com um scatter. Veja link: https://jsfiddle.net/r0duyz8b/2/

Estou certo que não estou fazendo da forma correta, pois se eu clicar para esconder uma das populações, o gráfico fica errado.

Alguém tem alguma sugestao de como fazer isso?

obrigado

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, João! Por favor faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o site! O que você quer dizer com "o gráfico fica errado"?

Comment: Se possível, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/219725/edit) sua pergunta e inclua mais informações de qual resultado você espera.